# Ionic app icon not change in android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, icons

I have project in `ionic`, I already set icon using `ionic CLI`.

In iOS the icon is changed, but in android its not changed.

Here is my config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

I checked plaftorm/android/res but icon and splashscreen are not changed.

I delete and re add the platform but it has no effect.

EDITED:

I sure image exists in resources directory and like I said before i already use ionic CLI command `ionic resources`

this my resources icon
[image: file]
this icon in platform ios
[image: file3]
and this icon in platform android
[image: file2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a cordova issue. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1608
Uninstall cordova(6.4.0) and downgrade it to 6.3.1

npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@6.3.1

After that remove the Android platform and add it again.

Comment: As mentioned in the Github issue, just upgrade the android platform to v6.1.0 fixes the issue: `ionic platform remove android && ionic platform add android@6.1.0`. Thanks for the link to the issue that helped me a lot btw.

Comment: If you are using the latest version then try this ionic cordova platform remove android && ionic cordova  platform add android@6.1.0

Answer (score 3):

**TO CHANGE IONIC DEFAULT APP ICON**

If you're using windows PC to execute your CLI. Do these 5 STEPS action

**`STEP 1`**

install capacitor resources by running *`npm install capacitor-resources -g`*

**`STEP 2`**

Create just 4 customized images (app icon, splash screen, icon background, and icon foreground) using any image editing software.

a. **app icon** -  *`(a png file with dimension 1024x1024)`* and save as *`icon.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/`* Let it replace the default

b. **splash screen** - *`(a png file with dimension 2732x2732)`* and save as *`splash.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/`* Let it replace the default

c. **icon background** - *`(a png file with dimension 432x432)`* You may decide to make the color transparent or not and save as *`icon-background.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/android/`*

b. **icon foreground** - *`(a png file with dimension 432x432)`* and save as *`icon-foreground.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/android/`* icon foreground is just same as app icon. it is the logo that will represent your app in app collections.

**STEP 3**

let capacitor help you to make the icon and splash in multiple dimensions by running

*`ionic cordova resources`*

**STEP 4**

copy the resources to the android build by running *`cordova-res --skip-config --copy`*

**STEP 5**

then run either of the following from the project directory, depending on whichever works for you. number 1 worked for me.

1. *`cd android && gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..`*
2. *`ionic cordova run android`*