# My android app icon on phone screen doesn't show up after download

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently published an app to google play store that was built with ionic v1. the app is showing up fine on the play store when searched and showing the correct icon.. but when i download the app, it shows a different icon on my phone screen. Also the splash screen shows the incorrect icon when i launch the app. The icon looks sort of like a box or block with a cat or fox like figure with blue eyes. I have ran ionic resources multiple times to generate the icons/splashscreens images and have checked to make sure all images are generated... the config.xml file seem to have all the path correct also. Please, any help is appreciated. thank you.

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>
```

Comment: ` like a box or block with a cat or fox like figure with blue eyes` that is `cordova's icon.`

Comment: What command are you using to generate apk?

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457905/ionic-app-icon-not-change-in-android